# How to get second last page as a number without hyperref?

Tags: lastpage

I'm trying to get the second last page as a number but without having to create a hyperlink to it.

What I have now is:

```
\def\leavesecond#1#2#3!{#2}
\makeatletter
\AtBeginDocument{%
  \expandafter\ifx\csname r@LastPage\endcsname\relax
    \newcommand\SecondLastPage{{\bfseries??}}%
  \else
    \newcounter{butlastpage}%
    \setcounter{butlastpage}{\expandafter\leavesecond\r@LastPage!}%
    \addtocounter{butlastpage}{-1}%
    \newcommand\SecondLastPage{}%
    \edef\SecondLastPage{\arabic{butlastpage}}%
  \fi}
```

Which works, the problem is that I'm having some compatibility issues with fancy-preview due to a hyperlink created to the last page. Is it possible to define it without creating the hyperlink?

Comment: Do you want to have the logical page number or the absolute page number?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Packages `lastpage` and `refcount`

Package `refcount` helps to get the page number from the reference `LastPage`:

```
\documentclass[a5paper]{article}
\usepackage{lastpage}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{refcount}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newcommand*{\thesecondlastpage}{%
  \the\numexpr(\getrefbykeydefault{LastPage}{page}{0})-1\relax
}
\AtBeginDocument{\refused{LastPage}}

\begin{document}
The second last page is \thesecondlastpage.

\lipsum
\end{document}
```

This produces three pages, the first run reports -1 as second last page, because `LastPage` is not yet available. The final run reports 2, because the document has three pages.

**[Caveat: Does not work like this for version 2023-07-24 v2.0c of the lastpage package. Update to version 2023-10-06 v2.0d of the lastpage package and everything works again.]**

## Package `zref-lastpage`

Modul `zref-lastpage` uses the `zref` referencing system to set a reference `LastPage` at the last page. This can also be used to get the page number of the last page to calculate the previous one:

```
\documentclass[a5paper]{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{zref-lastpage}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\thesecondlastpage}{%
  \the\numexpr(\zref@extractdefault{LastPage}{page}{0})-1\relax
}
\AtBeginDocument{\zref@refused{LastPage}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
The second last page is \thesecondlastpage.

\lipsum
\end{document}
```

## Package `zref-totpages`

Modul `zref-totpages` of project `zref` provides `\ztotpages` as absolute number of pages. Depending on the document numbering, it can also be used to get the second last page:

```
\documentclass[a5paper]{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{zref-totpages}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newcommand*{\thesecondlastpage}{%
  \the\numexpr(\ztotpages)-1\relax
}

\begin{document}
The second last page is \thesecondlastpage.

\lipsum
\end{document}
```

Comment: I'm still having compatibility problems with fancy-preview. In the first (and the second) run to search the labels, it is getting a label `\fancypreviewnewlabel{LastPage}{{}{25}{}{page.25}{}}` that results in a error. Is there any way to do that without using the package lastpage?

Comment: @user80175 I have no idea, what you are doing. Where does `\fancypreviewnewlabel` comes from? Which packages are you using? MWE? My answer variants provide `\thesecondlastpage`, which expands to a plain number without any links and can be used safely, even inside `\csname`.

Comment: I'm sorry about my question being incomplete. The problem is that this funtion comes in a user-created class, which would create a huge question to a very specific problem. That's why I tried to put the problem the most general way possible to be solved. Also, the `\fancypreviewnewlabel`comes from a script fancy-preview, which is very specific and the question would end up being huge.

Anyhow, using zref-totpages works ike a charm. Again, sorry for not being more specific in my question