# Doing math with \pageref (finding the last page number and adding 3)

Tags: cross-referencing, calculations

So I'm writing an exam. It will have some as-yet-unknown number of pages P, and an additional 3 pages of a formula sheet. So the total length is N = P +3.

I need to write "This exam has $P$ pages, plus $3$ pages of formulas, for a total of $N$ pages".

I currently have a label at the end of the exam: `\label{lastpage}`, and so where I have `P, I can write`\pageref{lastpage}`.

But is there some way I can get N to be calculated automatically for me? I suspect it might exist in `pgfmath`, but I haven't used it in a while.

Comment: See https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/250401/194703 (of course you'll need `\the\numexpr(\ztotpages)+3\relax`).

Comment: Thanks @Schrödinger'scat , Looks like that will work... Is there a way I can set a variable to be 3, so that I only have to make 1 change if the formula sheet length changes? If this is worth a separate question, let me know.

Comment: You can just define a macro like `\def\mynum{3}` and then `\the\numexpr(\ztotpages)+\mynum\relax`. (Some users on this site have a very strange behavior I must say.)

Answer (score 3):

Consider using [`refcount`](//ctan.org/pkg/refcount); use `\getpagerefnumber{LastPage}` in some calculation of your choice.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{refcount,lastpage}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

Last page: \pageref{LastPage}

Final page: \number\numexpr\getpagerefnumber{LastPage}+3\relax

\sloppy\lipsum[1-50]\lipsum[1-50]\lipsum[1-50]\lipsum[1-50]\lipsum[1-50]

\end{document}
```

Comment: This is more or less exactly what is done in https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/250401/194703.

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat: Nice. I'm pretty sure we can close this as a duplicate; while the question is asking for something different, the solution is pretty much the same.